# Using a where clause in a combination with a subquery which result is a record containin an array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I found some results/answers, regarding searching in array, but:

1. `WHERE = ANY`, works with a column, but not with a `subquery` that returns one record that contains an array as a result, triggers error
2. WHERE IN, also triggers the same error
3. I also tested `untest` on the subquery, similar error as the first 2
4. I don't want to check if a value is in an array but get/execute the query for the values in the array, like `WHERE IN (1,2,3,4)`, not like in the other questions/answers

The error:

> No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.

or

> No operator matches int = int[]

path is an `int[]`array type.

Structure:

```
id | name |  | slug   | path | parent_id
1    name1     slug1     {1}      null
2    name2     slug2    {1,2}     1
3    name3     slug3   {1,2,3}    2
4    nam4      slug4   {4}       null
```

What I tries as base:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.slug FROM types AS t
WHERE t.id in (SELECT t.path FROM types AS t WHERE t.id = 24)
ORDER BY depth ASC
```

Basically path is like a `breadcrumb` , `{grandparent,parent,type}`

Comment: First you should use different shortcuts for the main query and the subquery, using t twice is hard to read, at least. Second, since ANY works with a column, try to write it as inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one using `IN` and `unnest()`

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1."name",
       t1.slug
       FROM types t1
       WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT un.e
                              FROM types t2
                                   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(t2.path) un (e)
                              WHERE t2.id = 2)
       ORDER BY array_length(t1.path, 1);
```

And another one using the array is contained by operator `<@`.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1."name",
       t1.slug
       FROM types t1
       WHERE ARRAY[t1.id] <@ (SELECT t2.path
                                     FROM types t2
                                          WHERE t2.id = 2)
       ORDER BY array_length(t1.path, 1);
```

And one using `= ANY`.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1."name",
       t1.slug
       FROM types t1
       WHERE t1.id = ANY ((SELECT t2.path
                                  FROM types t2
                                  WHERE t2.id = 2)::integer[])
       ORDER BY array_length(t1.path, 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5f8a5abc7a43daae29e97419709aee44)

You didn't include `depth` in your sample data so I replaced it with `array_length(t1.path, 1)` which is probably what it is.